# NullPointerException when trying to reload IndexedContainer with fresh data

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to "reload" an IndexedContainer with new fresh data, but get a NPE.

I have a `addItemsToContainer(List<Person> persons)` method that I use to populate my container.

Let's say my Person list contains 100 person objects. When I **first** call `addItemsToContainer(List<Person> persons)`, my container is populated and everything is fine.

However, the **second** time I call the method, I get a `NullPointerException` in setValue().

Now, it seems like `removeAllItems()` *do* remove all items, but all *ItemId's* are left in the container. This means that the second time I call the method, the first automatically generated ItemId is `101`. Is this the reason I get the NPE? When debugging, I can see that I get the proper value back from `person.getId()`.

My addItemsToContainer method

```
public void addItemsToContainer(List<Person> persons) {

    removeAllItems();

    for (Person person : persons) {
        Object itemId = addItem();
        getContainerProperty(itemId, "Id").setValue(person.getId()); // <-- NPE here
        getContainerProperty(itemId, "Name").setValue(person.getName());
    }
}
```

The stacktrace 
*(`ExampleMainTableContainer.java:94` is the statement I marked in the addItemsToContainer method)*

```
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:170)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1371)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in com.example.myapp.web.view.ExampleView$1 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:167)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:368)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.myapp.web.view.ExampleMainTableContainer.addItemsToContainer(ExampleMainTableContainer.java:94)
    at com.example.myapp.web.view.ExampleMainTable.addMainTableItems(ExampleMainTable.java:172)
    at com.example.myapp.web.view.ExampleMainTable.experiment(ExampleMainTable.java:86)
    at com.example.myapp.web.view.ExampleView$1.buttonClick(ExampleView.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: In which line exactly does the NPE appear?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It gets thrown when I'm trying to set the value. Please see my updated original post. NOTE: The NPE gets thrown the *second* time the addItemsToContainer-method is called, not the first.

Comment: Please decompose the line where the NPE gets thrown as far as possible by using local variables and doing one thing at a time. That means do IndexedContainer c = getContainerProperty(...); Object personId = person.getId(); c.setValue(personId); all on different lines. then have a look which part causes the NPE.

Comment: Yes I already did. In my original post I do state that it happens in the `setValue()` method, which is a method of the Vaadin Property Interface. I cannot debug more than this - as soon as I get the value back from person.getId() the NPE is thrown.

Comment: Please, post full stack trace here. Also, dealing with NPE, you need to specify exactly which of these objects is null. Is it container property or person?

Comment: I agree with default locale: Please post full stack trace.

Comment: Please see my updated OP, where I posted the stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry for asking this again. Are you sure that `getContainerProperty(itemId, "Id")` doesn't return null? Can you check  it?

Comment: @Daniel S. @default locale You guys were right. getContainerProperty(...) did return null. I dug a little deeper and found this: `if (isFiltered()) { return getFilteredItemIds(); } else { return getAllItemIds();}`
... which means it returns an empty list --> ultimately leading to the getContainerProperty(...) method returning null, because I did actually filter the items in the container before this. Thanks a lot for your input and help, it sure lead me to find the cause of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The method `getContainerProperty(...)` returned null, leading to the NPE.

This happened because I filtered my container prior to the second call to `addItemsToContainer(...)`.

When I add a new item to my container, it gets added to `allItemIds` - the `filteredItemIds` is left empty. Now, when `getContainerProperty(...)` is called, it does a check if the container was filtered. If it was filtered, it returns `filteredItemIds` instead of `allItemIds`. This meant, of course, that this statement returned an empty list of objects, leading to ´getContainerProperty(...)´ returning null - which finally lead to the NPE.

**The solution** was to simply add `removeAllContainerFilters();` before my ´getContainerProperty(...)´ calls.